# Iterative call to a function on d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I want to call a function when clicking in several check box controls,

```
$('input[name=filt_box_gen]').click(function() {  
nodescheckclick(this,1);
})
```

so I have made an array with the control names,

```
var nodesfilterlist = ['input[name=filt_box_gen]','input[name=filt_box_que]','input[name=filt_box_ans]'];
```

... but only to be able of making it work still calling to the functions three times, one for each case...

```
$(nodesfilterlist[0]).click(function() {
nodescheckclick(this,0);
});

$(nodesfilterlist[1]).click(function() {
nodescheckclick(this,1);
});

$(nodesfilterlist[2]).click(function() {
nodescheckclick(this,2);
});
```

How could I iterate through the array to call the `nodescheckclik` function with just one?

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't d3, this looks like a jQuery question (jQuery is one library that uses the $ as a selector function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, this is more a javascript or jQuery question than a d3.js one.

You can use the built-in `forEach()` function for arrays. Namely:

```
nodesfilterlist.forEach(function(d,i){
    $(d).click(function(){nodescheckclick(this, i)})
})
```

With `d` being the element in the array and `i` the index of the element in the array.

---

Now, if you are actually using d3 and if your `nodefilterlist` is the data you are dealing with. Then you would have something like:

```
var nodes = d3.select("#checkBoxContainer") // Container for checkBoxes
    .selectAll("#checkBox") //name it as you wish, will create as many elements as there is in the data
    .data(nodefilterlist) //append the data you want to use
    //.attr("color", "blue") // would set attributes to data
    .on("click", nodeschecklist) //perform action on data
```

You don't even have to write more for the `nodeschecklist` call as it will automatically be translated as expected (`.on("click", function(d, i){nodeschecklist(d,i)})`) as both versions have the same signature.

Comment: Did you really mean to add svg? It shouldn't be required in this context as d3js can be used to deal with html elements (in pretty much the same way you would with jQuery). Assuming a division with id checkboxContainer exists, d3.select('#checkboxContainer').selectAll('checkBox').data().andSoOn